# Typescript error when using next-connect - This expression is not callable. Type 'typeof import(...)' has no call signatures

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-connect

I am trying to implement a function where a file will be uploaded to the public folder of the nextjs app using next-connect. But getting a typescript error -

> This expression is not callable.
> Type 'typeof import("d:/directory/file-upload/node_modules/next-connect/dist/types/index")' has no call signatures.

Api Codes in - *api/fileUpload*

```
import nextConnect from "next-connect";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
const apiRoute = nextConnect({
  onError(error: { message: any }, req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    res
      .status(501)
      .json({ error: `Sorry something Happened! ${error.message}` });
  },
  onNoMatch(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    res.status(405).json({ error: `Method '${req.method}' Not Allowed` });
  }
});
```

I am getting the mentioned error on the 3no line.

I was following this [link](https://morioh.com/p/c7ad109c8fd4).

Can Anyone help me what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

`onError` and `onNoMatch` should be key and values should be function.

```
const apiRoute = nextConnect({
  onError : (error: { message: any }, req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    res
      .status(501)
      .json({ error: `Sorry something Happened! ${error.message}` });
  },
  onNoMatch : (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse)=> {
    res.status(405).json({ error: `Method '${req.method}' Not Allowed` });
  }
```